# The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore

Tags: angular, vb.net

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ))

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```